# How can I request permission to access our precise location on the user's iPhone? in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Seeking guidance from #ReactNative devs: How can I request precise location permission on iPhone? Need help implementing in my app. Tips and code examples appreciated! Thanks! #LocationPermission

Refer to any packages or suggest any ideas also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get location in React Native, you can use react-native-geolocation-service.

You can get the location using the following code.

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => {
    const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error.code, error.message);
  },
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
);
```

But to use the code above, you need to ask for permission to use your location.

In iOS, you can get permission to use location with the following code.

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

Geolocation.requestAuthorization('always');
```

For details, see: [github](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service)

Happy coding!